# XNA Error on Creation or Loading a Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, xna, project

Hi Everyone i seem to be getting this Error with VS2013 Ultimate,

[image: The Exact error]

I have no idea how to fix it, i tried redownloading VS and re-installing and it did not fix the issue, this happens when trying to open an XNA project and trying to create a new one.

Comment: You should really use MonoGame instead. It's pretty much the same codebase, but much more friendlier.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just downloading the regular XNA release? It doesnt work with VS2013, only 2010. This site has a version which should work with VS2013:

https://msxna.codeplex.com/releases/view/117230

Comment: However i dont believe this error is caused by that